# jQuery animate "complete" callback firing too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) `.animate` has a parameter called 'Complete' that should only fire once the animation has finished. Unfortunately I'm finding that it fires *before* the animation has even started.

```
if ($('html').scrollTop()) {
    $('html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, callback);
    return;
}
```

JSFiddle showing the problem: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/5zu90ygz/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `callback` parameter should be a `function pointer`.  It's not a term used very often these days, but it means that you pass the function itself, not the *result* of a function.

What does this mean?

Given the example:

```
function message(q) {
    alert(q);
}
```

Here, `message` is a function.  To pass that function as a `callback`, use the name of the function, eg:

```
setTimeout(message, 100);
$("#id").click(message);
```

Note that there's no `()` after the name of the function.

In javascript terms, the function itself is a variable and you pass the variable, but as soon as you add `()` you are calling the function and passing the result, not the function itself.

If you use `message()` then the function will be executed and the *result of the function* passed as the `callback`, ie:

```
setTimeout(message("x"), 100);
```

is the equivalent of:

```
var x = message("x");
setTimeout(x, 100);
```

So you can see from this code why message runs immediately (more obvious with click event or longer timeout).

The format `setTimeout(message, 100);` isn't used very often as a) it looks like a typo (should that be `message()`?) and b) it doesn't allow you to pass a parameter, so this would frequently be written as:

```
setTimeout(function() { message("x") }, 100);
```

which uses an *anonymous in-line function* as the `callback` variable / function pointer.

---

Back the question:

In your [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/5zu90ygz/), all you needed to do was change the `callback` to a true `callback` without the need to add a separate parameter, ie:

```
$('#scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    scrollToTop(function() { message("Reached Top")});
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zu90ygz/9/

Comment: Thank you. I knew there were some issues with the other solution. There were things that were changed for no reason, and mentions of issues that weren't issues at all. I'm amazed it got so many upvotes to be honest (although it ended up in a reasonably good state in the end). Your explanation is perfect and very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling the function `message` when registering it as callback in the statement `scrollToTop(message('Reached Top'));`. Here the function `message` will be called and the returned value will be passed to the `scrollToTop` function.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3aawvoj1/1/)

You can pass an extra parameter to the function `scrollToTop` i.e. message to be displayed and then this message can be forwarded to the `message` function after animation completes.

```js
// Scroll to the top and fire callback
function scrollToTop(callback, message) {
  // Send the message as the second parameter

  if ($('html').scrollTop()) {
    $('html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, function() {
      // Call the callback function with the message as param after completion of animate
      callback(message)
    });
    return;
  }

  if ($('body').scrollTop()) {
    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, function() {
      // Call the callback function with the message as param after completion of animate
      callback(message)
    });
    return;
  }

  callback(message);
}

// Dummy callback function to fire
function message(q) {
  alert(q);
}

// On click event
$('#scroll').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  
  // Add message as second parameter
  scrollToTop(message, "Reached Top! Yay!");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<a href="#" id="scroll">Scroll to top</a>
```

Comment: You're no longer passing the parameter to the callback function. That's no help to me :( Also, `message()` is NOT called by `scrollToTop()` -- did you skim-read the code? That's a fallback incase the browser is already at the top of the screen.

Comment: You can use `bind` if you want to give the message as an argument of `scrollToTop`.

Comment: @QuentinRoy Yes, you can, but that'll replace the original context in case If OP still want to access it inside the function

Comment: @Tushar I downvoted you because your code has unnecessary elements that you apparently didn't understand from my original code. You still think that `message()` was being called by `scrollToTop()` so you removed it... but you kept the `if` statements in(!). Very odd. The rest of your changes are good and helpful. Correct your code and I'll happily accept and upvote. Thanks for your help, my code works fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/5zu90ygz/8/